# Does "SO_REUSEPORT" (OS X) or "SO_REUSEADDR" (Linux) really allow the user to use recvfrom for multiple sockets?

Tags: c, linux, macos, sockets, udp

I am writing a very beginner's code of UDP sockets on OS X (10.9.4), which uses multiple UDP sockets bound to the same IP address and port. I thought that using `SO_REUSEPORT` would allow me to receive packets through multiple sockets. But in the following example, only one of two sockets can receive data (i.e. `client2` which binds a socket to the port after `client1`).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class UDP
{
private:
  uint32_t           fSocket;
  struct sockaddr_in fSourceSocketAddress;
  struct sockaddr_in fDestinationSocketAddress;

public:
  UDP(const std::string& source_host, uint16_t source_port,
      const std::string& dest_host,   uint16_t dest_port);

  void Send(const std::string& str);
  std::string Receive();

};

//______________________________________________________________________________
UDP::UDP(const std::string& source_host, uint16_t source_port,
         const std::string& dest_host,   uint16_t dest_port)
{
  fSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  int on = 1;
  errno = 0;
  setsockopt(fSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (char*)&on, sizeof(on));

  memset(&fDestinationSocketAddress, 0, sizeof(fDestinationSocketAddress));
  fDestinationSocketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dest_host.c_str());
  fDestinationSocketAddress.sin_port = htons(dest_port);
  fDestinationSocketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

  memset(&fSourceSocketAddress, 0, sizeof(fSourceSocketAddress));
  fSourceSocketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(source_host.c_str());
  fSourceSocketAddress.sin_port = htons(source_port);
  fSourceSocketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

  errno = 0;
  bind(fSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&fSourceSocketAddress, sizeof(fSourceSocketAddress));
}

//______________________________________________________________________________
void UDP::Send(const std::string& str)
{
  char buffer[100];
  strcpy(buffer, str.c_str());
  sendto(fSocket, buffer, str.length(), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&fDestinationSocketAddress, sizeof(fDestinationSocketAddress));
}

//______________________________________________________________________________
std::string UDP::Receive()
{
  fd_set fds;
  FD_ZERO(&fds);
  FD_SET(fSocket, &fds);

  struct timeval tv = {1, 0}; 
  int nselect = select(fSocket + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
  if(nselect == 0 or !FD_ISSET(fSocket, &fds)){
    return "";
  } // if

  char buffer[100];
  recvfrom(fSocket, buffer, 99, 0, NULL, NULL);
  buffer[99] = '\0';

  return std::string(buffer);
}

//______________________________________________________________________________
int main()
{
  UDP client1("127.0.0.1", 8000, "127.0.0.1", 8001);
  UDP client2("127.0.0.1", 8000, "127.0.0.1", 8001);
  UDP server ("127.0.0.1", 8001, "127.0.0.1", 8000);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    server.Send("Hello");
  } // i

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    std::cout << "Client 1 received: " << client1.Receive() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Client 2 received: " << client2.Receive() << std::endl;
  } // i

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the result of this example code.

```
$ ./a.out         
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: Hello
```

But my expected result is as follows.

```
$ ./a.out         
Client 1 received: Hello
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: Hello
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: Hello
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: Hello
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: Hello
Client 2 received: Hello
Client 1 received: 
Client 2 received: 
(snip)
```

How can I make it possible to receive "Hello" by the both two sockets? I would also like to make the code compatible with Linux (kernel 2.4). I tried using `SO_REUSEADDR` instead of `SO_REUSEPORT` on Linux, but I got the same result as on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SO_REUSEPORT` and `SO_REUSEADDR` are used to allow another application (process) to use the same address immediately after your program is complete; they have nothing to do with multithreading in the same program.

What you're seeing is two threads getting notification of a sent message, but only thread 2 is dequeing the message because it was the last one to request the port.

A few things to think about:

Servers usually listen on only one port.  There is no reason to have the remote address specified, since that can be obtained from the client message.  If you are specifying the address and port of the client *from* which you expect to receive messages, then you will be unable to handle requests from any other client anywhere.

Clients typically (some special cases, like FTP and NFS use specific client ports as a security measure) open a new port to communicate with a server. Specifying the port from which you will be connecting restricts how many clients can run on the same machine.

Also, with UDP (excluding multicast) there is no connection preamble, so until the client has sent a message to the server, the server has no way of knowing that a client exists, much less what its address is.

I hope this helps; there is no code that can directly fix your problems here since it is based on some fundamental misunderstandings of UDP and socket programming in general, but inverting your work (have the clients communicate to the server, and the server responds to each client seperately) should help to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you @Greyson for clarifying that `SO_REUSEPORT` is not for enabling my purpose. The man page of OS X and Linux were not clear on this point at least for me. Please do not care about the detail of my example code. In realty, I don't use this a bit strange client/server model, indeed it does not exist in my application.